# Turn off and turn in time of Mosfet

Tags: mosfet

Why mosfet have different turn on and turn off time? If I am correct, mosfet have higher turn off time. Why?

Comment: You're not correct. To the conditions specified, mosfets have the turn on and off times that are specified.

Comment: It's application dependent.